# Parsing string toother data types in C

Tags: c

If I read the contents of the buffer into a string, how do i parse it in C?

lets say, I wish to parse a string in the following format:

store first 16 bits in an integer,
store next 32 bits in another integer,
store remaining string data as hex.

Comment: Do you mean a human-readable string, or a chunk of memory starting with a 16-bit integer, followed by a 32-bit integer, etc.? If the former, show your string format

Comment: its a chunk of memory with first 16 bits as an integer, the next 32 bits as another integer, and the remaining bits in the string as a hex value.

Comment: _All_ "strings" in C ends with a `\0`.  This implies the first 6 bytes may not contain a `\0`, else the string is too short.  Is it your intention to not allow integers values that contain a `\0`?

Comment: OK, so it's not normally called a string unless it's human-readable (either ASCII or some other encoding). This is a binary buffer. The next question is: what endianness does it use?

Comment: @Useless A C string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.  The human-readability and encoding is not a factor.  But I certainly agree the post is missing clear goals.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want something like the following (don't forget validations)

```
int first = (text[0] << CHAR_BIT) + text[1];
int second = (text[2] << (CHAR_BIT * 3)) +
             (text[3] << (CHAR_BIT * 2)) +
             (text[4] << CHAR_BIT) +
             text[5];
char *rest = text + 6;
```

Comment: you forgot to mention that tis for big endian processors only.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:
`int1` & `int2` integers are the same endian as in the buffer.
`s` alignment may not meet `int` needs.

```
#include <stdint.h>
void codeara_parse(const char *s, int16_t *int1, int32_t *int2, int8_t **rest) {
  memcpy(int1, &s[0]           , sizeof *int1);
  memcpy(int2, &s[sizeof *int1], sizeof *int2);
  *rest = &s[sizeof *int1 + sizeof *int2];
}
```

Otherwise OP needs to specify the endian-ness of the buffer.